# I can't Apply All to prefabs of maximo AJ character in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I can't `overrides` to `Apply All` in existing AJ `prefabs` of maximo, I have a added additional components of Rigidbody and Capsule collider.

Please find attached screen shot for information, I need your help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVS60.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your screenshot you can see that the Aj prefab already contains the RigidBody and the Capsule Collider and hence you can do apply all. 
If you are trying to create different versions of a prefab , you can select you prefab in the scene,right-click -> Unpack prfeab completly  and recreate the prefab again with a new name.